# $K$ field, $R$ subring, $t\notin R$, $R[t]$ has $t$ nonunit. Why is there a valuation ring containing $R[t]$ with max ideal $M'$ s.t. $M\subset M'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> $K$ field, $R$ subring, $t \notin R$ but $t \in K$, $R[t]$ has $t$ in a maximal ideal $M$. Why is there a valuation ring with maximal ideal $M'$ that contains $R[t]$ and has $M \subseteq M'$?

**Context**: Given a field $K$ and a subring $R$ and an element $t$ that is not an element of $R$, I'm trying to find the extent to which we can find valuation rings containing $R[t]$ with $t$ in their maximal ideals, in an effort to understand the structure of the proof of Corollary 5.22 in Atiyah-Macdonald.

**Argument**: Here's a proof the statement in the question should be true: A-M 5.21 tells us, given an arbitrary ring $R$ and a map to an algebraically closed field $f:R \to \Omega$, we can extend the map to $f:V \to \Omega$ where $V$ is a valuation ring containing $R$. Therefore, if $M$ is the maximal ideal of $R[t]$ which contains $t$, the composition of the quotient map and embedding map $R[t] \to R[t]/M \to \Omega$ to algebraic closure of $R[t]/M$ can be extended to $\phi:V \to \Omega$, and we have $\phi(t) = 0$, meaning $t$ is in the maximal ideal of $V$.

That being said, I don't understand why the only way we can make the above point requires the proof to take this specific form. Why are we even involving an algebraically closed field? Wouldn't any field that maps $t$ to $0$ do the job? i.e., although I understand the proof formally, I still don't see why our desired valuation ring should exist from a more intuitive point of view.